# background color of table row flashes after fadein with jquery

Tags: jquery, cell, fadein, background-color

Well, this is about as basic as you can get!  I'm inserting a row to the end of the table and immediately hiding it.  After I add the cells, I colorize the backgrounds, alternating light green and white.  I also have some alternating blue and white for densely packed columns.  The text fades in fine, but once it finishes, the background colors flash for a second or two.  Obviously, this kills the 'wow' factor with 'it must be amateur night.'

UPDATE: Created a demo table to show the effect...sort of (it only works in FF for now).  If you set the border="1" on the table, everything looks fine when you add a row, with the entire cell blue or green. If you set the border to 0, you see the area around the cell change turn white, then back to the original color.  So it looks like the last thing rendered is the border.

HOWEVER, this isn't quite the effect I'm seeing. In my table, the *entire* background for the cell flashes like this.  The text and some color fade in for 1/2 second, then the background goes white for 1/2 second, then back to the color.

UPDATE2: I made the cells much larger, so you can see that it's the entire background except for behind the text that changes color.  If you change the border to '1', it works as expected.

```
<style type="text/css">
table#demo  {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing:  0px;
  border-style:    none;
  font-size:       10px;
}

table#demo th {
  font-size:      10px;
  text-align:     center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  border-style:   none;
    border-width:   0px;
}

table#demo td {
  font-size:       10px;
  text-align:      left;
  vertical-align:  top;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight:     none;
  padding:         0px 8px 0px 8px;
  border-style:    none;
  border-width:    0px;
}

.even_row2 {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.odd_row2 {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
</style>

<table id="demo_table" class="demo" border="1">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th width="75px">col 1</th>
  <th width="75px">col 2</th>
  <th width="75px">col 3</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" onclick="addRow();" value="Add a row">

<script type="text/javascript">

var demoRowCnt=0;
function addRow() {

  ++demoRowCnt;

  var tbody = document.getElementById('demo_table').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
  var rowObj = tbody.insertRow(tbody.rows.length);   
  $(rowObj).hide(); 

  var colNo = -1;
  var cell   = rowObj.insertCell(++colNo);
  cell.innerHTML = 'r' + demoRowCnt + ' c1';  

  cell   = rowObj.insertCell(++colNo);
  cell.innerHTML = 'r' + demoRowCnt + ' c2';  

  cell   = rowObj.insertCell(++colNo);
  cell.innerHTML = 'r' + demoRowCnt + ' c3';  


  // my colorRows function:
  var rowStyle = 'even_row2';

  for ( var r=0; r<tbody.rows.length; ++r ) {
    rowStyle = ( rowStyle == 'even_row2' ) ? 'odd_row2' : 'even_row2';
    var str = ( MSIE ) ? 'className' : 'class';
    tbody.rows[r].setAttribute('class', rowStyle);

  }

  $(rowObj).fadeIn("slow"); 

}
</script>
```

Comment: could you create a jsFiddle that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: what do you mean by flash? which colours flash? what's the code for colorRows? 
without knowing the answer for my questions i can only suggest doing $(rowObj).fadeOut(0) instead of hide

Comment: This is unbelievable...I spent about 30 minutes working on a demo, and it works perfectly.

Comment: I've given up on this.  The table row fades in fine if I put 'border="1"' in FF but the color 'blinks' if not.  And I just found out that fadeIn doesn't even work in IE8, the official browser for work here.